# Get the difference between two sentences

Tags: php, string, intersection

I am trying to get the difference between two sentences in Php,
for example

```
$a1 = explode(" ",'This is just a tweet tweet');
$a2 = explode(" ",'waste of time This is just a stupid tweet get a life');

//I need the output to be Statement1:waste of time Statement2:stupid Statement3: get a life

function fullArrayDiff($left, $right)
{
    return array_diff(array_merge($left, $right), array_intersect($left, $right));

//This does not take care of the 
}
```

I tried the Longest common sequence but it did not get what i wanted

Can any body help on that Is there a name for this algorithm
Thanks in advance

Comment: still not well defined.  Since there can be various places where two sentences don't match, and various ways to splice things together that should "cancel out" it is not obvious what the difference between two sentences should be.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Text_Diff package

http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/docs/latest/Text_Diff/Text_Diff.html